# Why would an uploaded Xerox PDF cause a 418 error?

Tags: php, apache, printing

I am trying to upload a pdf generated by the scanner on a Xerox AltaLink 8055. The upload works as expected with every PDF I have found with the exception of the ones generated by the Xerox. I am getting a 418 error and find this in the logs:

```
[Tue Mar 12 13:04:24 2019] [error] [client IP_ADDRESS] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 418 (phase 2). Matched phrase "GLOBALS" at ARGS:artworkfile64. [file "/dh/apache2/template/etc/mod_sec2/99_dreamhost_rules.conf"] [line "256"] [id "1990070"] [msg "Common known arguments for backdoor shell present in ARGS:artworkfile64"] [hostname "DOMAIN_NAME"] [uri "/srom/orders-details-submit.php"] [unique_id "XIgQx0Wj@@AAAFN90ZAAAAAB"]
```

I am using a Dreamhost VPS. If I open the file and re-save it with Preview or Acrobat then the upload works as expected.

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: 418? Are you trying to send the file to a teapot?

Comment: @kuh-chan The file is converted to base64 on the client browser and then stored in a mysql database. The error page says "418 unused"

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a [mod_security](https://modsecurity.org/) rule on your VPS, specifically line 256 /dh/apache2/template/etc/mod_sec2/99_dreamhost_rules.conf. (This information is in the log line you pasted.)

You can try to disable this specific rule by commenting it out in the configuration file, or disable mod_security entirely for your site.